# SQLite Android обновление данных

Tags: android, sqlite

Всем привет. У меня такой вопрос, сейчас на своем приложении я сделал регистрацию и авторизацию пользователей, которая сохраняется в файле SQLite на приложении. Приложение уже опубликовано в Google Play. Вопрос если я выпущу обновление не "затрет" ли он все аккаунты людей, учитывая что в новой базе их просто не будет? Если это так , то как этого избежать? И подскажите сразу как можно получить доступ до записей приложения которое уже на Гугл Плей если пока не реализована админка где бы это отображалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

последний вопрос немного не понял, а так в SqlLiteHelper'e есть метод onUpgradge, и если ты версию бд не поменяешь, с базой данных ничего не случиться, а если поменяешь до запустится метод onUpgrade и что там напишешь то и будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь понял. Вопрос второй в том что сейчас все записи регистрации записываются в файл SQLite .db приложения который в Гугл Плей опубликован, я их технически получается не вижу или можно как то посмотреть этот файл, какие там регистрации произошли ?

Comment: вообщем попробую объяснить, не знаю будет ли полезно, вообщем у каждого телефона храниться локально своя SQLite.db, её с любого устройства взять нельзя, но можно скачать приложение, попробывать зарегистрироваться и вытащить из своего девайся эту бд или просмотреть с помощью приложений  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager (SQLiteManager) типо таких но для них помойму root нужен